# How to justify and print a paragraph using a 2d array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, justify

I have an assignment that basically is asking to justify a paragraph given line length. So for instance the paragraph
"I am a student of C, this is my first assignment. I hope I finish on time." given line length of 17 should be as follows:

```
output
I am a student of
C,   this  is  my 
first assignment.
I  hope  I finish
on          time.
```

I am having trouble with dynamically placing spacing in between the words. I currently have a function that counts the words in a paragraph and stores them into a 2d array but I have no idea how to a) calculate the amount of spacing in between words and b) how to dynamically print that justified paragraph.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
int getAllWordsFrom2DArray(char *paragraph, char words[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH]) {
    int i,j,totalWords = 0;
    for(i=0; i < strlen(paragraph); i++) {
        int wordLength;
        if (paragraph[i] == ' ' || paragraph[i+1] == '\0') {
            totalWords++;
            wordLength = i;
            for(j=0; j < wordLength; j++) {
                words[i][j] = paragraph[j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", words);

    return totalWords;
}


//Code in progress
int getNumberOfWordsForNextLine(int totalWords, int lineLength, char words[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH]) {
    int wordsForNextLine = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < totalWords; i++) {
        wordsForNextLine = 0 ;
    }
}

//code in progress
void printNextLine(int wordsForNextLine) {

}


//skeleton code provided by instructor
void justifyAndPrintParagraph(char* paragraph, int lineLength) {
    char words[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    int totalWords = getAllWordsFrom2DArray(paragraph, words);
    int processedWords = 0;

    while (processedWords < totalWords) {
        int wordsForNextLine = getNumberOfWordsForNextLine(totalWords, lineLength, words);
        printNextLine(wordsForNextLine);
        processedWords += wordsForNextLine;
    }
}
```

To clarify, we are not allowed to use strlok. Essentially we are expected to just use the basics in doing this. I need to use the void justifyAndPrintParagraph function and signature but other than that I'm free to do whatever.

Edit: I forgot to add that if spaces cannot be evenly divided then the extra spaces are to be allocated left to right.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks its been a while since I posted a question.

Comment: The way I see it is that you must first determine the maximum number of words that fit on a line. Let's call this `num_words`. In the extreme case of `num_words == 1`, you can just print that word and fill the rest of the line with spaces. Otherwise, there will be `num_words - 1` gaps between words that you have to fill with spaces, in order to fill the line. You must calculate the number of spaces that you must insert in total into that line, and spread these spaces evenly among those gaps.

Comment: You will have to calculate the number of spaces per gap, but, since the number of spaces will not always be evenly divisible by the number of gaps, you will also have to calculate the number of gaps that will receive an additional space.

Comment: This is a well-known (and very ancient) problem. A good explanation can be found at [Text Justification Algorithm](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse221/200910/Projects/Markov/justification.html).

Comment: Normally, the last line would not need the radical spacing — the last line of a paragraph can be shorter than full width.

Comment: How is it going? This is not a very nice first assignment. (And, I fear, I hope I didn’t influence you to mess with linked lists — you really don’t need them to solve it, it just makes handling special conditions that you don’t need to worry about easier...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider how many spaces you have to distribute. For example, given the input:

```
18
I am the very model of a modern Major-General.
```

Computing the number of words that fit on the line goes:

```
"I" + "am" + "the" + "very"           + (4-1 words) --> 13
"I" + "am" + "the" + "very" + "model" + (5-1 words) --> 19
```

So only the first 4 words fit on an 18-character line. The number of space characters to distribute are then easily calculated:

```
N = max_line_width - sum_of_word_lengths
```

Now for the hard part: how many spaces between each word? Your homework expects you to divvy extra unbalanced spaces left-to-right, meaning that each pair of words may have a *different* number of space characters.

However, the difference will always be **a single space character**. Take a moment to convince yourself this is true:

```
I···am···the··very
-2-4-6-8-0-2-4-6-8
```

In our little example, we find that there are *three* space characters in the first two inter-word spacings, and *two* space characters in the last.

The *minimum* number of space characters per inter-word spacing is easy enough to caluclate:

```
nsp = N / (number_of_words_in_line - 1)
```

<sup>Beware! What happens if you have only *one* word on the line? (Do you really need to distribute spaces for such a line?)</sup>

And now, for the cool tricky math part, you can calculate the number of times you need to add a space to the inter-word spacing as:

```
nplus1 = N - nsp * (number_of_words_in_line - 1)
```

or just:

```
nplus1 = N % (number_of_words_in_line - 1)
```

<sup>Keep in mind that it is possible that all inter-word spacings are the same number of space characters, and may be exactly *one* space character even. Notice how our calculations work just as well in those cases.</sup>

Now you can print the words for the line in a loop, adding `nsp` space characters after every word, plus an extra space after the first `nplus1` words.

<sup>Remember, the *last* word of the line doesn’t get any spaces. It is followed by a newline!</sup>

Hopefully this should help you work your way through this assignment.
(I personally think it is a bit of a careless assignment as your first ever, introduction to C class.)

And now, if I have made errors, it is because I am very, very sleepy. Someone will surely point it out if I have.

Comment: Thank you very much, this response got me on the right track and I believe I found the solution. I do agree its a bit of a careless assignment for our first C assignment but after speaking with the instructor she believed that we had exposure to C before. We had only studied Java up until now which doesn't quite prepare you for C especially with the pointers etc.

Comment: Programming language, in general, doesn’t really matter. You should be able to apply algorithms to similar data structures in any language, so your prof might not have been far off. Anyway, glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

So using Dúthomhas' suggestion I was able to create the function below:

```
void justifyAndPrintLine(char words[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], int processedWords, int amountOfWordsForNextLine, int lineLength) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = processedWords; i < processedWords + amountOfWordsForNextLine; i++) {
        total += (int) strlen(words[i]);
    }
    int spaces = lineLength - total;
    int spacesBetweenWords = spaces / (amountOfWordsForNextLine - 1);
    int spacesRemaining = spaces % (amountOfWordsForNextLine - 1);
    int spaceForThisWord;
    int leftWords = processedWords + amountOfWordsForNextLine;
    while (processedWords != leftWords) {
        spaceForThisWord = spacesBetweenWords;
        if (spacesRemaining > 0) {
            spaceForThisWord++;
            spacesRemaining--;
        }
        printLine(words[processedWords], spaceForThisWord);
        processedWords++;
    }
}
```

A key part of my understanding of the math was that the difference in spacing was always going to a single space character. Borrowing his math I was able to properly justify the paragraph. Thanks again Dúthomhas!

Comment: Don’t forget to test this on lines containing a _single_ word — as you cannot divide by zero.